# Page not centering in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, alignment, center

Works fine in Safari but IE7 it left aligns. http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585#ht_500wt_1372

Any way of making it so it centres in IE too? Thanks

```
.container {
width:980px;
background-position: center;
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
font-size: 12px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="clear">dfgfdg</div>

</div>
```

EDIT:

Anybody got an eBay account to test on too? Cheeky I know but am sure a lot of people would benefit!

EDIT 2:

This code still renders to the left and is really annoying because it can be done:

```
.wrapper 
{
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: 980px;
text-align: center;
}


.container
{
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}

</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.your content here.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Renders this: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585#ht_500wt_1156

Example of centered page on eBay: http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Argos-Outlet (have checked code and seems to use same code as suggested below but still can't get it to work at all.

Comment: If you don't have a background image, there's no need for background-position. It doesn't do what you're hoping for.

Comment: what does the eBay link have to do with this? Are you just trying to boost hits to that item?

Comment: Evan, I was skeptical at first as well. However, if you look down at the "full description" area, you'll notice that Kelly is trying to position these elements in the center for that description.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/GweVX/

---

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0; /* have some north + south padding */
    background-color: #feefee; /* enter your background color */
}
.aligner {
    display: block;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers this element */
    text-align: center; /* centers the text */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="aligner">
        Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet, amet sit dolar ipsum lorem.
    </div><!-- /aligner -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Thanks so much I tried that but no such luck.! Real issue maybe to do with the Iframe of eBay? Updated link: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585#ht_500wt_1413

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this:

```
.clear{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Works for me when I put IE9 into IE7 mode. (No way to test on real IE7.)

Comment: Thanks but text needs to be left aligned within the divs?

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
    position: absolute:
    margin-left: -490px;
    left: 50%;
}

<div class="center">&nbsp;</div>
```

This centers the DIV as well

Comment: That sounded really promising until it failed for me yet again. I think I may throw in the flag on this one soon.. http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585#ht_500wt_1413 "test 2". Last thoughts at all please??!

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin: auto;` to `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`

To make the text aligned to the left, put `text-align: left;`

Comment: Cheers please see EDIT 2 above

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you div with another one with this:

```
.wrapper 
{
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: 980px;
text-align: center;
}

.container
{
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
```

and then the html will go like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    your content here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: since IE can't read `margin`, to be able to position the div at the center, use `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: Cheers please see EDIT 2 at top of this page for response.

Comment: add this to your <style> `body{text-align: center;}` I think that'll do the trick.